# Explanation of DPDT Relay circuit (Used as SPDT) for cutoff

Tags: circuit-design, relay

I need help explaining how this circuit works and what the purpose of each components is.
This circuit was used in my semester project and I want to be able to understand and explain it.

Thanks in advance :D

[image: Cicuit Diagram]

Comment: What was your semester project? It's quite a bad schematic so if you want to understand it, you should redraw in a logical fashion.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fc-FUzGCwIQ

Comment: Nobody's going to watch a video.

Comment: Why? It is only around 1 min.

Comment: Questions must be self-contained and not rely on links that may become flaky in a week, or a month or a year.

Comment: Okay I see, valid point btw.To answer your question it is a autonomous cart for shopping.

Comment: This is **your** project. You **already designed it**. If you don't know how it works, withdraw from the class and concentrate on being a "wizx gamer".

Comment: Have a great day!

Comment: To avoid closure of your question you should edit it to explain what it does - your title says "cut-off" so explain what it cuts off - what the green and red LEDs are supposed to indicate, why there is a diode in the battery, etc. What was the specification for the circuit? What is "an autonomous cart for shopping"?

Comment: Ok will do, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The negative side of the battery is connected to the charger's -VOUT trough diode D2. The purpose of this diode is most likely to prevent reverse current flow from the battery back into the charger when the charger's voltage is lower then the battery's (For example, when the charger is powered off).

The positive side of the battery is connected to the charger's +VOUT trough a normally closed contact of the relay. So when the relay's coil is *not* energized (off) the battery will charge.

The RED LED is connected to this same relay contact so that it will illuminate while the battery is charging.

A typical battery charger will output a constant current, not a constant voltage. As the battery is charging with this constant current, it's voltage will rise. R1 and RV form a resistive voltage divider, configured so that around 0.7V will appear on the base of transistor Q when the battery reaches it's target voltage. This will cause Q to start conducting and turn on the relay.

Once the relay is turned on the battery and RED LED are disconnected from the charger, so the battery stops charging, and the charger is connected to the GREEN LED, causing it to illuminate to indicate the battery is full.

Because the battery is now disconnected from the constant current charger, the charger's voltage will rise to it's maximum, which makes sure Q keeps conducting and the relay stays on.

R2 limits the current trough the RED and GREEN LED.

D1 allows a path for the relay coil's freewheeling current to flow when the relay is turned off, preventing a voltage spike that would possibly damage Q.